# I am trying to create a javascript page to enter information into a form and it's not working

Tags: javascript, html

order.html
[This is a form that is supposed to be filled with information using the javascript "script.js" page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Eating Well in Season - Signup</title>
      <!-- 
         Eating Well in Season Signup page
         Filename: order.html

         Author:   Janae Roland
         Date:     11/13/17
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit M, Independent Challenge 4
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="android.png">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="header-nav-container">
         <p class="skipnavigation"><a href="contentstart">Skip navigation</a></p>
         <header>
            <h1>Eating Well in Season</h1>
            <div>
               <img src="logo.png" width="216" height="146" alt="a flower on an orange background with white letters">               
            </div>
         </header>
         <nav class="sitenavigation">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="sources.html">Sources</a></li>
               <li><a href="menus.html">Sample Menus</a></li>
               <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
               <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="article-aside-outer-container">
         <div class="article-aside-inner-container">
            <article id="contentstart">
               <h2>Order</h2>
               <form action="results.html">
                  <fieldset class="address-options">
                     <legend>Choose an address</legend>
                     <div class="two-column">
                        <input type="radio" id="homeoption" name="shippingaddress">
                        <label for="homeoption">Home</label>
                        <p>1 Main St.</p>
                        <p>Sicilia, ME 03900</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="two-column">
                        <input type="radio" id="workoption" name="shippingaddress">
                        <label for="workoption">Work</label>
                        <p>15 Columbine Ln.</p>
                        <p>Crab City, ME 04993</p>
                     </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset class="contact-info">
                     <label for="streetinput">
                        Street Address
                        <input type="text" id="streetinput" name="streetinput">
                     </label>
                     <label for="cityinput">
                        City
                        <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="cityinput">
                     </label>
                     <label for="stateinput">
                        State
                        <input type="text" id="stateinput" name="stateinput">
                     </label>
                     <label for="zipinput">
                        Zip
                        <input type="text" id="zipinput" name="zipinput">
                     </label>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset class="submitbutton">
                     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                  </fieldset>
               </form>
            </article>
            <aside>
               <h2>What&rsquo;s In Season</h2>
               <p>Baby Carrots</p>
               <p>Cardoons</p>
               <p>Chard</p>
               <p>Fiddleheads</p>
               <p>Mint</p>
               <p>Morels</p>
               <p>New Potatoes</p>
               <p>Ramps</p>
            </aside>
         </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
         <p>Eating Well in Season &bull; Glover, VT &bull; (802) 555-3947</p>
      </footer>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

script.js
[This page is supposed to enter address and work information into a contact form for the order.html page. It is not working, I've validated the page and fixed everything that I can. I'm wondering where I went wrong,and if there is anything I need to add to the syntax.]

```
/* Eating Well in Season
       Filename: script.js
       Author: Janae Roland
       Date:     11/13/17
       HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit M, Independent Challenge 4*/


 /* Create Variables */
 var homeOption = ("#homeoption");
 var workOption = ("#workoption");
 var streetInput = ("#streetinput");
 var cityInput = ("#cityinput");
 var stateInput = ("#stateinput");
 var zipInput = ("#zipinput");


 /* Add Home Information */
 function homeAdd () {
      streetInput = "1 Main St.";
      cityInput = "Sicilia";
      stateInput = "ME";
      zipInput = "03900";
      if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
          submit.Button.className = "submitbutton show";
      }
 }

 /* Add Work Information */
 function workAdd () {
     streetInput = "15 Columbine Ln.";
      cityInput = "Crab City";
      stateInput = "ME";
      zipInput = "04993";
      if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
          submit.Button.className = "submitbutton show";
 }

 /* Event Listeners */
 homeOption.addEventListener("click", homeAdd, false)
 workOption.addEventListener("click", workAdd, false)
```

Comment: I would just like to add a little clarity to the situation. If I seem like I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm a student, I'm really new to anything past html and css and I'm just learning and trying to figure this out one day at a time. If you can please bear with me I'd be so grateful. Any help is so greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. You’re missing a `}` and neither `submit` nor `form` are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues here:

1. You have not referenced any JavaScript library, so getting element by Id using your method is not possible. (("#homeoption");)
2. Following code:

> var homeOption = ("#homeoption");
>
> var workOption = ("#workoption");
>
> var streetInput = ("#streetinput");
>
> var cityInput = ("#cityinput");
>
> var stateInput = ("#stateinput");
>
> var zipInput = ("#zipinput");`

Should be changed to `document.getElementById("homeoption");`

3. Your workAdd method is missing `}`.
4. You cannot assign value directly to a DOM object:
   `streetInput = "1 Main St.";`
   You should use `streetInput.value = '1 Main St.';`

Comment: I've added the missing "}" and added the ".value" to my statements. and changed my variables to "var variableName = document.getElementById("homeoption");"   I am not using a java library,there were no instructions in my assignment to do so. Thank you for the help. But the information still isn't displaying in the form when I select the radio buttons.

Comment: Ok. I have created a JS Fiddle based on my comments. https://jsfiddle.net/juty7e6w/ Please check. I have commented form.checkValidity() because that one is not coded in your sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much. The program you provided works perfectly. And now I can clearly see what I was missing that was causing the problems. I really didn't get a clear outline of how to add in these aspects from my assignment instructions. I was wondering if there is any way that I can have these files separate and still get them to work the same. (Such as having a script.js file linked to the order.html file). If you can help I'd be very grateful

Comment: I am glad it helped. Mark it as answer then? You can still put your javascript in a separate file as you we doing in the first place. Since JsFiddle didn't allow to put in files, I had to do like than

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thanks again. I'll mark it as an answer. I appreciate this very much.

Answer (score 0):

order.html
[Correct code for this file]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Eating Well in Season - Signup</title>
      <!-- 
         Eating Well in Season Signup page
         Filename: order.html

         Author:   Janae Roland
         Date:     11/13/17
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit M, Independent Challenge 4
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="android.png">
   </head>
  <body>
      <div class="header-nav-container">
         <p class="skipnavigation"><a href="contentstart">Skip navigation</a></p>
         <header>
            <h1>Eating Well in Season</h1>
            <div>
               <img src="logo.png" width="216" height="146" alt="a flower on an orange background with white letters">               
            </div>
         </header>
         <nav class="sitenavigation">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="sources.html">Sources</a></li>
               <li><a href="menus.html">Sample Menus</a></li>
               <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
               <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="article-aside-outer-container">
         <div class="article-aside-inner-container">
            <article id="contentstart">
               <h2>Order</h2>
               <form action="results.html">
                  <fieldset class="address-options">
                     <legend>Choose an address</legend>
                     <div class="two-column">
                        <input type="radio" id="homeoption" name="shippingaddress">
                        <label for="homeoption">Home</label>
                        <p>1 Main St.</p>
                        <p>Sicilia, ME 03900</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="two-column">
                        <input type="radio" id="workoption" name="shippingaddress">
                        <label for="workoption">Work</label>
                        <p>15 Columbine Ln.</p>
                        <p>Crab City, ME 04993</p>
                     </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset class="contact-info">
                     <label for="streetinput">
                        Street Address
                        <input type="text" id="streetinput" name="streetinput">
                     </label>
                     <label for="cityinput">
                        City
                        <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="cityinput">
                     </label>
                     <label for="stateinput">
                        State
                        <input type="text" id="stateinput" name="stateinput">
                     </label>
                     <label for="zipinput">
                        Zip
                        <input type="text" id="zipinput" name="zipinput">
                     </label>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset class="submitbutton">
                     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                  </fieldset>
               </form>
            </article>
            <aside>
               <h2>What&rsquo;s In Season</h2>
               <p>Baby Carrots</p>
               <p>Cardoons</p>
               <p>Chard</p>
               <p>Fiddleheads</p>
               <p>Mint</p>
               <p>Morels</p>
               <p>New Potatoes</p>
               <p>Ramps</p>
            </aside>
         </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
         <p>Eating Well in Season &bull; Glover, VT &bull; (802) 555-3947</p>
      </footer>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

script.js 
[Correct code for this file]

```
     /* Eating Well in Season
       Filename: script.js
       Author: Janae Roland
       Date:     11/13/17
       HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit M, Independent Challenge 4*/


 /* Create Variables */
 var homeOption = document.getElementById("homeoption");
 var workOption = document.getElementById("workoption");
 var streetInput = document.getElementById("streetinput");
 var cityInput = document.getElementById("cityinput");
 var stateInput = document.getElementById("stateinput");
 var zipInput = document.getElementById("zipinput");


 /* Add Home Information */
 function homeAdd () {
      streetInput.value = "1 Main St.";
      cityInput.value = "Sicilia";
      stateInput.value = "ME";
      zipInput.value = "03900";
      /*if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
          submit.Button.className = "submitbutton show";
      }*/
 }

 /* Add Work Information */
 function workAdd () {
     streetInput.value = "15 Columbine Ln.";
      cityInput.value = "Crab City";
      stateInput.value = "ME";
      zipInput.value = "04993";
      /*if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
          submit.Button.className = "submitbutton show";
          }*/
 }

 /* Event Listeners */
 homeOption.addEventListener("click", homeAdd, false)
 workOption.addEventListener("click", workAdd, false)
```